# ¿Como obter estilos CSS con jQuery para que exista compativilidad entre Chrome y Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, chrome

Este código me funciona perfectamente con Chrome, sin embargo con Firefox no lo hace.

```
    var cropper_border_w =  (parseInt(cropper.css("border-width"))+1);
    var centrator_margin_left =  parseInt(centrator.css("margin-left"));
    var container_margin_left =  parseInt(container.css("margin-left"));
    var top = parseInt(centrator.css("top"));///nan


    var x = cropper.position().left - centrator_margin_left - container_margin_left - cropper_border_w ;
    var y = cropper.position().top - cropper_border_w;


    var h = cropper.height() + cropper_border_w*2;
    var w = cropper.width() + cropper_border_w*2;



console.log( x + " " + y + " " +h + " " +w + " " + cropper_border_w + " " + centrator_margin_left + " " + container_margin_left + " " + top);
```

Esta es la salida de "console.log()" es esta Para Firefox. En Chrome se obtienen valores numeriocos:

```
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 121 80 0
```

¿Cómo hago para que el código sea compatible con los dos navegadores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estaba pasando era que en Chrome si por ejemplo "border-width" no está definido la función cropper.css("border-width") devuelve cero mientras que en fireFox debuelve NaN... He tenido que hacer esto para que funcione en los dos navegadores.

```
var cropper_border_w =  (parseInt(cropper.css("border-width"))+1);
if(isNaN(cropper_border_w))cropper_border_w=0;
```